# Downloading Two Attachments In Same Email With Same Name

Tags: vba, outlook

There is a daily email with two attachments with the same name. I require both attachments to be saved to the specified location but one is overwriting the other.

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub Coronation(item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim today As String

    today = Format(Date - 1, "ddmmyy")

    'Folder save location
    saveFolder = "C:\Users\SChogle\Documents\Projects\VBA Projects\Email Save Collection\Drop Files"

    For Each object_attachment In item.Attachments
        If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".csv") Or InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".xlsx") Or InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".xls") Then
            object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & object_attachment.DisplayName & Format(Now(), "ddmmyyhhmmss")
        End If
        Sleep 1000
    Next

End Sub
```

I expect both attachments to be saved.

Comment: Are you saving always on the same folder? Are you replacing everyday the same files? In that case I'd check for the modified date on the ones with the same name. `If attach.name = item.save And item.savedate = today then` that'd be the pseudocode

Comment: object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & object_attachment.DisplayName_& ""format(now(),ddmmyyhhmmss) &""

Comment: hey man, i tried this but i have it as follows: ```object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & "Coronation " & Format(Now(), "ddmmyyhhmmss") & ".xls"``` is that correct? because it still seems to only be saving one attachment

Comment: @Damian hey man, thanks for the response but to be honest I don't really understand what you mean. but to answer your question yes I am saving in the same folder

Comment: @Saadiq well following techie's comment, maybe happens the same problem. The macro is saving both files so fast that it happens within the same second. I'd try to make it wait a second for every iteration just before the `Next`

Comment: @Damian oh okay that makes sense, any idea how I could force it to wait a second before downloading the second attachment?

Comment: @Saadiq  down here you have my answer with everything in line already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub test()

    Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim today As String

    today = Format(Date - 1, "ddmmyy")

    'Folder save location
    saveFolder = "C:\Users\SChogle\Documents\Projects\VBA Projects\Email Save Collection\Drop Files"

    For Each object_attachment In item.Attachments
        If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".csv") Or InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".xlsx") Or InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".xls") Then
            object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & object_attachment.DisplayName & Format(Now(), "ddmmyyhhmmss")
        End If
        Sleep 1000
    Next

End Sub
```

I've also indented your code so it's more readable and less prompt to errors for not closing instances. If you don't know how to indent, you can use RubberDuck from [Mathieu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mathieu-guindon)

Comment: Hey Damian, thanks so much for you effort! But unfortunately now nothing is being downloaded at all :(

Comment: Nothing changed on that part, just added the date format and the waiting time... Though I can't test this because there are missing declaration such as the `Item`.

Comment: Ok @Saadiq now it should work. Forgot that `Application.Wait` doesn't work for outlook. You need to add the second line on the top and use `Sleep`instead.

Comment: Why would you deliberately slow your application down for a complete second on a single match? I cringe just thinking about that at my office.  Much faster to increment an integer inside a Loop While Len(Dir(name & i ext))>0 then save the file after exiting the loop.  I've toyed around with various methods and have been happiest with   yymmdd-hhmm_yymmdd-hhmm_i_subject_filename. Where the first time stamp is built on Now, the second time stamp is the received date, incrementing indexer is added as needed, first 60 characters of the email subject, and the original filename.

Comment: Thats another way to go... in OP's case will save less than a second with your way :)

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't point a finger, my incrementing variable is actually a string that I convert to increment and that had to slow my job down by a second or two every few hundred years. But it's worth it to me because my code looks better and it's easier to read.  Pride of ownership I guess.

Comment: @Damian, added the line on the top and gave me some error about being needed to be updated for win64 bit systems so I added this instead ```#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else
    Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If``` however even after doing that and using sleep, still nothing

Comment: Thanks so much for your help but I give up now haha

Comment: See my exact code I have now in the edit in my question, is that correct? Maybe I am just an idiot lol

Comment: @Saadiq yeah, that code should work, it does for me.

Comment: @Damian just thought i'd let you know, I eventually figured out a way to do it. I used the index of the attachment to distinguish between the two attachments. Thanks for your help though!